# Wallch not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, wallch

After upgrade Wallch can't even start. When I start it from terminal it outputs this:

```
QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication
QDBusConnection: system D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
```

And then pauses without any signs of live.
How to repair this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1453849

Install the wallch-daily ppa provided from the Wallch Team.

First, remove the wallch configuration files:

```
rm -r ~/.wallch/ ~/.config/wallch/
```

Then, remove Wallch from your system, then run the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wallch/wallch-daily
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wallch
```

Your bug should be fixed. You will also get Wallch code updates within 24 hours, so you will be at the latest version, but you should expect some instability issues now and then.

More info: https://launchpad.net/~wallch

Comment: Latest build didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Please see the edit about removing the configuration files. In the mentioned bug report, it worked for the 2 persons involved.